# Read replica configuration in Rails is being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just finished following [RoR Multiple Databases with Active Record](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html) however, my Rails app still seems to be completely ignoring my read replica configuration. In fact, I specifically made a typo in the hostname and have never been able to trigger an error yet on reading from the read replica.

Here's my `config/initializers/multi_db.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.active_record.database_selector = { delay: 2.seconds }
  config.active_record.database_resolver = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver
  config.active_record.database_resolver_context = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver::Session
end
```

My `config/database.yml` file:

```
development:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    host: <%= Rails.application.credentials.development[:host] %>
    username: <%= Rails.application.credentials.development[:username] %>
    password: <%= Rails.application.credentials.development[:password] %>
    database: <%= Rails.application.credentials.development[:database] %>
  primary_replica:
    <<: *default
    host: aurora-prod-test.cluster-rox-.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
    username: <%= Rails.application.credentials.development[:username] %>
    password: <%= Rails.application.credentials.development[:password] %>
    database: <%= Rails.application.credentials.development[:database] %>
    replica: true
```

And in my `app/models/application_record.rb` file, I have specified:

```
connects_to database: { writing: :primary, reading: :primary_replica }
```

According to the article, that seems to be it. However, when I try a basic GET request, it doesn't seem to use the read replica. I have a typo in the name where it shows 'rox' instead of 'ro' and I'm not experiencing any errors, indicating that the read replica is not working properly.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: What's in your default config that you need to import into the database configs? `<<: *default`

Comment: Did you set `self.abstract_class = true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in Rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/45162

Was able to get it fixed by adding the code that belonged in `config/initializers/multi_db.rb` into my `config/application.rb` file instead.